# Carthage Installation: Build Failed Task failed with exit code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I'm having an issue when I try to `carthage update`

```
Build Failed
Task failed with exit code 65:
/usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -project /Users/Shared/projectLocation/source/Carthage/Checkouts/ActiveLabel.swift/ActiveLabel.xcodeproj -scheme ActiveLabel -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/main/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.4.1_9F2000/ActiveLabel.swift/1.0.1 -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath /var/folders/nx/tqnzdw9x5_d73x7tjcmvrv2r0000gn/T/ActiveLabel.swift SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in /Users/Shared/projectLocation/source/Carthage/Checkouts/ActiveLabel.swift)

This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please check the xcodebuild log for more details: /var/folders/nx/tqnzdw9x5_d73x7tjcmvrv2r0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.LEmVYA.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I resolved.
ActiveLabel.swift was updated on 10/9.
If you use Xcode9, please try to use the tag/0.9.0.
It's written in the below release note.
https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift/releases/tag/1.0.1